# Ошибка при попытке приведения типа

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста. При передаче в данный код значений определенного типа `int`, `long` и т.д.:

```
public static boolean convertToBoolean(Object value) {
    boolean returnValue = false;
    if (value == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (value instanceof Boolean) {
        return (boolean) value;
    }
    String objvalue = (String) value;
    for(int i = 0; i < TrueArray.length; i++) {
        if(objvalue.equalsIgnoreCase(TrueArray[i])) {
            returnValue = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Появляется ошибка, к примеру:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: `String objvalue = (String) value;` а что вы хотели получить?..

Comment: Мне приходится приводить в строку чтобы сравнить введенное значение с массивом и в случае совпадения вывести True, иначе False. Как то так

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы получить из объекта строку, вызывайте метод `toString()`, а не пытайтесь просто привести тип:

```
String objvalue = value.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Это плохой подход... Ваш метод принимает сам не знает что. Методы instanceof , toString - очень медленные. Будете злоупотреблять ими - получите огромное падение производительности. Подумайте, какие типы может принимать ваш метод. Насколько я понял это Boolean и String. Отлично, так почему бы вам не перегрузить метод для этих типов?

```
public static Boolean convertToBoolean (Boolean value) {
    return value == null ? false : value;
}

public static Boolean convertToBoolean (String value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) return false;
    for (String arrayValue : TrueArray) {
        if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(arrayValue)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Для сведения... value.equalsIgnoreCase(arrayValue) - это выражение при значении null в переменной value дает исключение, но если null будет в аргументах, т.е. в том случае в переменной arrayValue, то все нормально отработает. Следовательно, если ваш массив состоит из нескольких элементов и в него не могут попасть null,  то проверку на null  можно и не делать, просто изменить выражение в условии так arrayValue.equalsIgnoreCase(value).

Обратите внимание, что TrueArray - переменная, хранящая ссылку на массив, а переменные принято именовать с маленьких букв. Может Вам покажется это мелочью, но за это вообще-то отбивают руки и правильно делают...